# Unable to update property using enum

Tags: ios

I used an Enum code that is

```
-(void)setLabelTextForCategory:(MyFoodCategory)category
{
    switch(category) {
        case MyFoodCategoryVegetable:
            self.categoryLabel.text = @"Vegetable";
            break;
        case MyFoodCategoryMeat:
            self.categoryLabel.text = @"Meat";
            break;
        case MyFoodCategoryFish:
            self.categoryLabel.text = @"Poisson";
            break;
        case MyFoodCategorySweet:
            self.categoryLabel.text = @"Dessert";
            break;
    }
}
```

However I get an error that says property categoryLabel not found on object type of "ViewController". Am I doing something wrong or did I forget something

Update
 Ive only written this code and nothing else

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, MyFoodCategory){
MyFoodCategoryVegetable = 0,
MyFoodCategoryMeat = 1,
MyFoodCategoryFish = 2,
MyFoodCategorySweet = 3,
};
```

Comment: Please show the code where you declare the `categoryLabel` property for that view controller.

Comment: "property categoryLabel not found on object" - then frankly, why is the title "enum doesn't work"? I mean, seriously, this has nothing to do with the enum whatsoever...

Comment: Have you declare "categoryLabel" property?

Comment: @AppleDevram I am just following your questions for last 3 days. My advice is you should really read some iOS documentations or some online tutorials. You are simply asking several questions when each error you got. Just search in google to solve it. go through the http://www.raywenderlich.com tutorials atleast. This is a simple error you can clear by just typing in google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your error message, you have not defined the property `categoryLabel` in your view controller; this has nothing to do with `enum`s. I expect you need to define a property similar to the following below:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *categoryLabel;
```

Make sure you link this property to your label in IB (ctrl-drag a line between them)

Comment: Forgot to link it thank you